# How to backup Exception Site List in Java Control Panel?

Tags: 14.10, java, jdk, jre

I'm backing up my laptop before formatting and re-installing it.

I would like to back up the "Exception Site List" in the Java Control Panel so I will not have to re-insert all sites again.

The window is question:
[image]

How can it be backed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `~/.java/deployment/security/exception.sites` file.